# Tool for extracting "fragment URLs"? (E.g. www.example.com#section)

Tags: html, firefox-extensions, url, links

Does such a thing exist?

E.g. a Firefox Extension (or other kind of browser script) where you can right-click on the subtitle in a section of any webpage you want to link to and it will give you the link with hash symbol and section name like in the title of this question.

I know it's possible by looking in the page source or using Firebug but ideally want to avoid that type of thing e.g. so my mum could use it.

(If there's no such tool out there I'm tempted to write one...)

Comment: You are looking for the term "anchors": https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/show-anchors/

Comment: Thanks, very helpful - looks like the newer version is here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-anchors-2/ and does exactly the job I wanted. If you'd care to put that in an answer I'll gladly accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `anchors` is used for the URL segment after the hash `#`.  There are extensions in most browsers that will expose these anchors in a way that makes copying easy.

To avoid future dead links, these are searches:

> Show anchors in [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=show%20anchors)
>
> Show anchors in [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/show%20anchors?hl=EN)